# Replace values in spreadsheet with assigned decile value (1-10) for multiple columns

Tags: r, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet with 20 year time series data for 100 firms. The names of the 100 firms are in the first column, followed by each column containing values for a particular year (21 columns).

I would like to replace the values in each column with the assigned decile distribution for each firm in that particular year. How would I go about doing this in R?

Comment: Please add relevant tags to question: R != spreadsheet

Comment: More importantly add code for what have you tried along with example data and expected output. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.